# Is there a function that gives me a file name without path?

Tags: python, path

I want to turn `C:\abc.bmp` into `abc.bmp`, or even better, if possible, in `abc`. That is easy to do with .NET as there are functions for both goals. Is there anything similar in python?

Comment: WHen you read about the `os.path` module, what did you learn?  http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
>>> os.path.basename(r'C:\abc.txt')
'abc.txt'
```

for basename only:

```
>>> base, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(r'C:\abc.txt'))
>>> base
'abc'
```

Comment: What is the r for? So I don't have to do \\ ?

Comment: @devoured: Yes, the 'r' means "raw" string, a string literal without embedded escapes.

Comment: Yes, exactly that. It stands for a "raw string": http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals

Answer (score 3):

Try `os.path.basename()`.